# Why is a function getting pruned from my Angular library's service when compiling with --prod?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have built an Angular 6 library containing a service with several public functions.

This library and service works fine when called from the library's "App", even when the app is built with --prod, which enables "aot".

In a separate, newly-created NG project, the library is imported as an npm package (the library package is always built using the --prod flag), and everything works normally **unless** the new project is built using the --prod flag.  I'm assuming this is related to the "aot" functionality.

In the new project, with the same service instance (injected via DI), one of the functions is callable like normal, and one very similar function is pruned and doesn't exist to be called.  If I recompile the same project without specifying `--prod`, both functions exist and can be called normally.

My question is - what are things I can troubleshoot or look for to figure out why this is happening, and ultimately to remedy?

--

For reference, I am building the library .tgz using this command:

`ng build --prod my-library
cd dist/my-library && npm pack`

Comment: Can you say what's the difference between the two functions?

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter - I can even duplicate/rename the working function, and give it a new name, and it's not working.  I'm continuing to troubleshoot, and for some reason, only the first function works...with the exact same name.  Even if I just rename the function, the new name is not accessible.  Almost like something is cached in the optimizer....and - again, everything works fine in the local host Angular project where the library resides.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Angular's build optimizer is caching the node_module that is my library.  This was happening even though I updated the minor build version before every "publish" to .tgz file.

After deleting the cache file for my library, and rebuilding the Angular project, everything is working normally.

Perhaps a major upgrade of the version number (instead of upgrading the minor number) would have busted this cache - I haven't tested that.

The build-optimizer cache is located here:
`\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\.cache`